# NCAA Bracket Auto-Generator: Grading Results

Tags: probability

I've written a pretty straightforward script to auto-generate a 2018 NCAA Men's Basketball Tournament bracket based on FiveThirtyEight's power rankings ([here](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2018-march-madness-predictions/) and [here](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/how-our-march-madness-predictions-work/)). For each head-to-head matchup, I calculate the probability for each team to win (eg, UCMB has a 2% chance to beat Virginia in the opening round) and then roll a virtual loaded die to choose the winner.

It's a pretty fun little tool: https://bracket.land/

But I'm always trying to tweak it and make it better, so I'm wondering if there's a way to quantify how safe or how risky a generated bracket is. I imagine the most risky bracket is to chose every single lower probability roll, and the most safe to do the inverse. But every other quintillion possibility is somewhere in between. So what number am I looking for and how do I convey how risky or safe it is for their bracket? I'd like to have some scale or set list of responses, eg, "Playing it safe, huh?" or "You're a risk taker!".

Clearly, I don't know much about stats and only so much to get this far, so thanks in advance for entertaining me! (And I hope someone gets their bracket filled out neatly bc of this thread).

Comment: Your use of the word "risk" seems a little non-standard.  If I'm interpreting correctly, "risk" means "relatively unlikely" to you. (Ordinarily, it is related to the possibility of an adverse outcome weighted by its chance of occurring.) So, to apply your sense of "risk," why don't you just report the chance of a bracket relative to the most likely one? A more challenging problem is to identify the most likely one! It's not necessarily the case that the greedy algorithm you describe--of choosing the most likely winner at each stage--actually is the likeliest scenario.

Comment: But I'm accepting that 538 has already done the "correct" work in giving me the probabilities for any head-to-head matchup. That's the premise I'm working under. Same as if I'm using BPI. I accept I'm not using the term risk properly, but part of what I'm attempting is translating the statistics into layman's terms/understanding for this tool. I know there must be a formula out there. Like, how much more likely (ie, 'safe') is it to pick 63 winners at 60% chance winning vs 63 winners at 40% chance winning so that your bracket ends up perfect?

Comment: I'm working under the same premises. But it doesn't follow that tracking the most likely head-to-head outcomes in the tournament yields the likeliest overall outcome. Consider a 4-team tournament where $a$ plays $b$ and $c$ plays $d$ in round 1. Suppose $a$ beats $b$ with 51% chance, $a$ beats either $c$ or $d$ with 51% chance, but $b$ surely beats either $c$ or $d$. To be concrete, suppose $c$ beats $d$ with 51% chance. Your algorithm has $a$ beating $c$ in the final, with a scenario probability of $0.51^3=0.133.$ The *likeliest* scenario is $b$ beats $a$ and then $c$: its chance is $0.2499.$

Comment: Okay, I think I'm tracking. So do I have to know the most likely scenario given seeding and probabilities, or can I add up the difference in chosen winner vs chosen loser probabilities in every head-to-head matchup? Like, keeping a running tally.

Comment: I don't think you actually need to know the most likely scenario. You could use the scenario you generated as a "baseline." Unless there are some strong nontransitivities like those I posited in my example, the baseline may indeed be the likeliest and we can expect it to be among the likeliest regardless. Thus, it might be possible for a user to produce a slightly more likely scenario, but most of the "risky" bracket-fillers will have much less likely scenarios. You will find that likelihood ratios can get really tiny, so for that reason (and theoretical ones) it's better to report log ratios.

Comment: Okay, so I guess that's why I posted this question--to get help with a formula. If I'm reporting log ratios, how do I do that knowing the probabilities with each head-to-head matchup?